How to fetch all the installed applications list from Android/Google TV to iOS application?
I am developing an android tv remote application in iOS. In this app I need to fetch all the installed applications in connected android/google tv to my iOS app.
it is possible? if yes then can anyone please help me out.

Use package manager apis in android to get all installed apps.
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager(); List<ApplicationInfo> installedApps = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
you will get all the installed apps on the OS TV
follow this link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager

thanks for the quick response but it is for android. it need it for iOS

i don't think you can access all apps of android in IOS. both are different OS. you can install something on the android first to access to IOS. am i right @Berlin?

I'm not sure about it? but yes I need it in iOS from the Android TV
